# How to run the local ng serve instead of the globally installed one with host 0.0.0.0

Tags: angular-cli

When running the global `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` everything works as expected seeing the web server bound to `0.0.0.0`:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

However if I run `npm run-script ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` I get an error saying:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Project '0.0.0.0' does not support the 'serve' target.
See "/tmp/ng-JQyvtf/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Then I try changing the arguments a bit `npm run-script ng serve --host=0.0.0.0` but the web server binds to `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

This issue occurs both in Angular CLI 8 and 9. Haven't tested with other versions.

Is there a way to run `ng serve` with host bound to `0.0.0.0` from local `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for this for a while:

`npx ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`